# Are there any modern musical "epics"?

Tags: lyrics, concept-album

Have any significant musical epics been created from the year 2000 forward? By "epic" I mean the literary term, as in a long narrative.

I'm interested in a song, multiple songs, album or band/artist with an actual plot-based narrative as well as the music that accompanies it, such as the concept albums by the band *[The Dear Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dear_Hunter)*.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you consider "relatively modern"?

Comment: By "relatively modern" I mean from the 21st century. 2000-2021

Comment: Are you looking only for self-contained songs or albums, or would you include long stories spread across multiple releases (possibly containing unrelated material too) such as R. Kelly's [Trapped In The Closet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapped_in_the_Closet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of music out there, but in terms of sticking to well-known musicians, a few come to mind: All the albums for both the Dutch progresive rock band Ayreon and the American neo-soul/hip-hop auteur Janelle Monae are fitted loosely into **epic science-fiction narrative continuities**. The plot for Ayreon's projects is more well-defined, and deals with a future apocalypse, and the attempt to salvage scraps of humanity through time-travel. Monae's continuity also deals with time-travel, and revolves around the efforts of rebel android/cyborg Cyndi Mayweather to find love, while fighting to free her people from being enslaved by human beings. The most recent of her albums, *Dirty Computer,* was accompanied by an actual SF film linking the song's music videos into a unified plotline. Ayreon began in the 90s, but continues through today, whereas Monae's solo debut was 2007. A similarly SF-themed narrative can be found in the work of the concept-based "virtual band" *Gorillaz*, whose entire decades-spanning ouevre can be viewed as the extension of the original conceit.

At a more realist level, the work of indie rock bands Fountains of Wayne and Arcade Fire can be seen as depicting extended storylines about large casts of characters in **well-defined suburban milieus**.

In terms of single albums, concept albums continue to be made with unified overarching narrative storylines. A notable recent one was American hip-hop collective the Roots' *Undun* (2011), which depicts **the last day in a young man's life** in reverse order (it was inspired by the 1999 Prince Paul album *A Prince Among Thieves*, which has a similar concept).

Pop-music powerhouse Beyonce has also dropped multiple "**visual albums**," which, like Monae's *Dirty Computer*, weave together an album's worth of music videos into a single plotline. These include *Lemonade*, her powerful exploration of the emotional fallout of her husband's affair (Jay-Z's *4:44* was the "he said" side of the conversation), and *Black is King*, a loose retelling of the narrative of the movie *The Lion King* with human protagonists.

Answer (score 0):

[Dream Theater - The Astonishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Astonishing) is one of many concept albums the band has released.  Many "Prog Metal" acts have done a few concept albums, from [Fates Warning - A Pleasant Shade Of Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pleasant_Shade_of_Gray) to [Vanden Plas - Christ 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_0) to [Haken - Aquarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarius_(Haken_album)) all contain complex music and lyrics woven into stories, usually with some sort of Sci-Fi twist.

Comment: The others are all good candidates, but *Pleasant Shade of Gray* (1997) is outside the OP's timeframe. Time flies, doesn't it? :D

Answer (score 0):

Some concept albums from the metal genre which might fit the description:

[Judas Priest - Nostradamus (2008)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostradamus_(album)) Double album based on the life and prophecies of the 16th century seer Michel de Nostredame, "Nostradamus".

[Within Temptation - The Unforgiving (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unforgiving) There were movies, comic books and the music all released around the same time, all telling some manner of female protagonist urban good vs evil story.